# unable to compile ecepass.c

Tags: c, gcc, freebsd

I can not for the life of me compile this old code. I'm attempting to use it to test external vulnerabilities for a client. I have it running in FreeBSD 11 and compiling with gcc. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

```
int in_cksum(u_short *addr, int len)
{
    int sum;
    int nleft;
    u_short ans;
    u_short *w;

    sum = 0;
    ans = 0;
    nleft = len;
    w = addr;

    while (nleft > 1) {
      sum += *w++;
      nleft -= 2;
    }
    if (nleft == 1) {
      *(u_char *)(&ans) = *(u_char *)w;
       sum += ans;
    }
    return (sum);
}
```

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/MGSYycmB

Error:

> In file included from ecepass.c:8:0:
>   ecepass.c:72:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
>    int in_cksum(u_short *addr, int len)

Comment: I'm think you forget to include something... joking

Comment: @Stargateur Have you looked at the full source? He's including practically *everything* :)

Comment: And he's including a bunch of them twice.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it was in there twice. I took them out but it didn't make a difference in the error.

Comment: I have a horrible suspicion, which I can't test myself because I don't have convenient access to FreeBSD 11.  Please change the name of the function `in_cksum` to, I dunno, `compute_in_cksum`, and then try recompiling.  (You will also need to change all callers to match.)  If that fixes it, I will explain.

Comment: @zwol umm that worked!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code posted on *PasteBin*, at line *#8* (and *#24* :d) there's the statement: `#include <machine/in_cksum.h>`

As I'm not on *Nix*, I've searched the file on Internet and found 2 references:

- [[GitHub]: osv/bsd/x64/machine/in_cksum.h](https://github.com/cloudius-systems/osv/blob/master/bsd/x64/machine/in_cksum.h)
- [[RTEMS]: source:rtems-libbsd/freebsd/sys/arm/include/machine/in_cksum.h @ ffcd542](https://devel.rtems.org/browser/rtems-libbsd/freebsd/sys/arm/include/machine/in_cksum.h?rev=ffcd542fe20b072cdb2b38ff36a62a2c62a4c6f2)

In both of them (around line *#40+*), seems like ***in_cksum* is a preprocessor macro**:

```c
#define in_cksum(m, len)        in_cksum_skip(m, len, 0)
```

Change the name of your function (and all the places in your code that reference it) to something that's not a macro, or another defined identifier as a matter of fact, e.g. *checksum* (hopefully it's not already defined :) ), and you should be fine (might apply to other of your functions as well).
Or as an alternative, remove the *machine/in_cksum.h* inclusion (direct **and** indirect (via other nested includes)), but this might get a little bit more difficult (also, I didn't check all the code to see if other functions from the include are used).

Comment: This allowed it to compile. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't have the details quite right, but "one of the system headers is defining in_cksum as a preprocessor macro" was my horrible suspicion.  A lot of the \*BSD-specific networking-related headers weren't written with namespace cleanliness in mind.

Comment: @zwol: Clearly, such a suspicion could only emerge from lots of experience in the area :)

Comment: @CristiFati Let's just say I still remember all three places you have to terminate a SCSI chain.

Comment: @sethh: Does this qualify as an answer to your question?